# Swift: how to check if string contain URL only

Tags: swift, url

From the server side, sometimes I am getting simple string, sometimes string that contains URL and sometimes URL only. How to check if that string contains URL only, no other text.

[image]

Comment: you have to be more specific, tipically the url is in the beginning of the string? post an example of the string

Comment: isn't it clear in question? there are three cases as mentioned above. I just want to check if string contain URL only

Comment: the url starts always with https: why you don't make a simple parcing with startwith("https:")?

Comment: if let myURl = URL(string: "https://url string") {

Comment: URL NOT always starts from http(s), what about file url? And so on

Answer (score 1):

Add below two functions into to your ViewContoller

```
func getUrlStringFromString(text: String) - > String {

var tempStrArray = text.components(separatedBy: " ")
var urlString = ""
    for i in 0 ..< tempStrArray.count {
        if isValidUrl(str: "\(tempStrArray[i])") {
            urlString = tempStrArray[i]
        } 
    }
    return  urlString
}

func isValidUrl(str: String) -> Bool {
    let detector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
    if let match = detector.firstMatch(in: str, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: str.endIndex.encodedOffset)) {
        // it is a link, if the match covers the whole string
        return match.range.length == str.endIndex.encodedOffset
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Then call `getUrlStringFromString` with your string

```
let urlString = self.getStringFromSting(text: YOUR_STRING)
if urlString != "" {
 //YOUR_STRING have url. and urlString contains URL
} else {
 //YOUR_STRING doesn't have url.
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: These methods aren't anything to do with views - and should _not_ be in a view controller. A better idea would be to have them in an extension on `String`